# Redirect from site.ru/idxxxxx to site.ru/name.php?id=xxxxx

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

How to create redirect from  **site.ru/idxxxxx** to **site.ru/name.php?id=xxxxx**

I can create redirect using .htaccess .
But how to get an id from first link /id**XXXXX** and put into second ?id=**XXXXX**
using .htaccess?

Comment: English only please

Comment: You might be looking or `pretty url`s. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Comment: use  `$_GET['id']` a sample code may help

Comment: Do you mean how do you create that url in the htaccess rewrite rule or inside php get the original path and generate a new url from it?

Comment: @PatrickEvans using .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rewrite rule in your htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^id(.*)$ name.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will match any characters after id

if you want to match it if only digits exists after id

```
RewriteRule ^id([0-9]+)$ name.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`[0-9]+` regular expression satisfies for any length of digits

`.*` matches matches any length of characters except newline.